# what is the correct syntax to create table in talnet software puTTy

Tags: mysql

Now since my first question was close out because the way I ask:
What is the correct syntax to create a table in telnet software puTTy:
here is what I place in the cursor 
mySql> create table Users
       (
         column name datatype,
         column name datatype,
       )
       ; now do we place the semicolon here: explain?
I through that stackoverflow is the place to ask question: Now I don't understand what is the correct way to ask a question?

Comment: This is a valid command: `CREATE TABLE example (
         id INT,
         data VARCHAR(100)
       );`

Comment: I don't even know where to start.  You are asking an SQL question.  This has nothing to do with the shell program putty.  Instead you should probably be using something like PhpMyAdmin to interact with databases manually until you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2):

First when you reach to `mysql>` u should use this command and then start making table:

```
use username_db;
```

this will update ur whole database and then u can start making query.

And u can insert `;` after each query and separate each column with `,` and if you use `int` as a data  type, no need to specify any size of `int`. And if u use `varchar`, u should specify the size of it. The query suppose to be like :

```
create table tablename (columnname datatype, columnname datatype);
```

if u make table Users then it can be

```
create table Users (id int, data varchar(10), answer varchar(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes may put semicolon (`;`) in the end but remove the last comma (`,`) before the closing brace (`)`);

```
 create table Users ( column name datatype, column name datatype) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can remove (,) at the end of the datatype and you can insert semicolon(;) after the end of each query. Here is the syntax for creating a table;

```
create table Users(column_name INT,column_name varchar(15)); 
If the datatype is INT you don`t need to create the size of the INT .Suppose if the 
datatatype is String you have to create the size of the string(like varchar(15)).
Let me know,If you need any more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table tablename (columnname datatype(size),columnname datatype(size));
```